# Circular dependency on React & Redux project

Tags: reactjs, redux

Supposing we have a project which has React components structure like this

```
<Parent>
  <Child />
</Parent>
```

So the `Parent` is depending on `Child` from the respective of React composition.

In addition to that, we also define selectors/actions for each component and group them by feature like

```
- parent
  - component
  - actions
  - selectors
- child
  - component
  - actions
  - selectors
```

In this case, we want to use selectors/actions of the `Parent` in `Child`, would that cause circular dependency? If so, what's the right way to resolve it?

Comment: This will not cause circular dependencies, since your selectors will be inside the ``selectors`` file, not the ``component`` file

Comment: @Tracer69 I also thought of that but I'm still wondering if that's a good practice in the case we have code splitting by feature, e.g. parent and child in two chunks